# Ember frontend with node backend - development practices

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, ember.js, proxy

I'm currently developing an ember frontend with a node backend.

In my ember-cli app I have an .ember-cli file set to proxy requests to node:

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

I've also had to set a whole bunch of rules in contentSecurityPolicy to avoid cross site issues.

I start ember with `ember server` and it does successfully proxy ajax requests to my node backend - although it also proxies ajax requests from other libraries such as facebook to node (which fail with 404s).

The ember content is served from `http://localhost:4200/`

I also have a static landing page served directly from node which I can access via `http://localhost:3000/home`

Is there a better way to set it up more like it would be in production where all of the content is served from one address? Or do I have to develop in this isolated mode?

A proxy in front of both apps might do the trick, but it would still need the contentSecurityPolicy things as nothing would really be different from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

In my latest application I've been using Ember.js for frontend and node.js + express + mongodb as backend.

I'm running 2 servers - nginx for `/dist` directory(static files, images etc.) on port 80 and node server for API on other port. I proxy requests that begin with `/api/v1`(dynamic requests) to express server:

```
upstream app_domainName.com {
    server ip.co.me.shere:1234; # port of node.js server running
    keepalive 8;
}

    location /api/v1/ {
            proxy_pass  http://app_domainName.com;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502
http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I don't want to serve static files via express server because nginx seems to have better performance for dealing with them.

Answer (score 0):

When you run ember serve, ember is constantly updating it's dist directory with each file save.

I symlink ember's dist directory into my server's directory, then I tell hapi that the '/' route should reply with a view that is basically a copy of ember's index.html file, and also open a route to /dist/assets (this is where all your ember js code is).

In terminal just open two tabs, on one run ember serve, on the second run your server.

This serves everything from your server's port, constantly up to date with each file save.

Comment: In your ember app's root directory, there should be a directory called dist. You need to symlink that dist folder into your server's root directory (or wherever you want - but it needs to be in your server's directory, not outside of it.) Then, tell your server to have one or more of it's routes point to that dist folder in your server directory. Then, in terminal just run ember serve, open a second terminal tab and run your server. Every time you update your ember files, the dist folder will update, meaning your symlinked dist folder in your server directory will update too.